# Best way to deploy a bcb6 application using mysql database?

Tags: mysql, c++builder

How/what is the best way to deploy an application written in bcb6 using mysql database.
what tool is the easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use VCL DAC for MySQL(http://download.cnet.com/DAC-for-MySQL/3000-2066_4-10066109.html)  or  odbc connect MySql.

```
try
{
    con->Connected=false;
    con->ConnectionString=ConnectStringmysql();
    con->Connected=true;
}
catch(Exception& e)
{
    ShowMessage("failed!");
    return;
}
```